# The all method not see the instance field values for subclassing keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, subclassing

For subclassing to create a Tensorflow model with the following code:

```
class MyClass(keras.Model):
    def __int__(
        self,
        input_shape: tuple,
        classes_count: int = 10,
        model_name: str = 'model_name',
        **kwargs,
    ):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(name=self.__class__.__name__, **kwargs)
        self.my_info = "foo"

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.my_info

        return x


var = MyClass((2, 2))
print(var.call("asd"))
```

The `call` method can't see the `self` field value:

> ```
>     x = self.my_info
> AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'my_info'
> ```

What am I doing wrong and how to get access to `self` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've called your constructor `__int__` rather than `__init__`. It didn't cause an error directly because `__int__` is a valid magic method and `keras.Model` has a default constructor.